# How do I configure Unity and my computer to run my game/project on Oculus Go?

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, oculus, oculusgo

I've been reading through the [Oculus for Mobile development basics](https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/mobilesdk/latest/concepts/book-mobile-basics/). There are tons of links everywhere, and it's unclear which steps are needed for GearGR and which ones are needed for Oculus Go, and it's just a mess and nothing's working. Is there a simple guide for how to just get everything going?

Answer (score 4):

## Install prerequisites

1. Install Unity
2. Install Android Studio
3. If you're running Windows, you'll have to [install the ADB drivers](https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/mobilesdk/latest/concepts/mobile-device-setup-go/). On a Mac, you're good to go and can ignore this step.
4. Launch Android Studio, click Configure in the bottom right corner, and click SDK Manager.
5. Under SDK Platforms, check every platform from API level 21 and above. Don't press Apply/Ok yet.
6. Under SDK Tools, enable Android SDK Build-Tools, LLDB, Android SDK Platform-Tools, Android SDK Tools, HAXM, NDK
7. Press Ok or Apply. A ton of stuff will be downloaded and installed. Afterwards the "Ok" button will be broken, so force-quit Android Studio.
8. If you're running Windows you have to [set up a bunch of environment variables](https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/mobilesdk/latest/concepts/mobile-studio-setup-android/). On a Mac, you're good to go and can ignore this step.
9. Note that for the Oculus Go (as opposed to the GearVR), you [do NOT need](https://forums.oculusvr.com/developer/discussion/comment/609696/#Comment_609696) an [OSIG file](https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/mobilesdk/latest/concepts/mobile-submission-sig-file/#mobile-submission-sig-file) for any purpose, development nor deployment. Just ignore every reference to it.

￼[image: android studio config menu]

## Enable developer mode

10. Open the Oculus app on your phone.
11. Settings > Tap your Oculus Go > Wait for it to connect... > More Settings > Developer Mode > Enable
12. It'll prompt you to create a developer organization in your dev dashboard. Tap the link and follow the instructions in the browser. You'll be creating an app and an "app id". **Save this app ID for later.** (see screenshot below)
13. Once you're done becoming an oculus developer and creating an app id, try to enable developer mode from your phone again; now it'll succeed.
14. Connect your Oculus Go to your computer with a USB cable.
15. In your terminal/shell, type `adb shell getprop`. It'll find your Oculus but it's unauthorized.
16. Without unplugging your Oculus, put it on your head and using the controller, tap the allow button in the Android permissions dialog.
17. Take off the headset, and try the `adb shell getprop` command again.

[image: app ID in the developer dashboard]

## Integrate Oculus into your Unity project

18. Create a new Unity project, or open an existing one.
19. From the Asset store, download "Oculus Integration", and import it into your project. You can select everything and just import it.
20. In your Project pane, under Oculus > VR > Prefabs, find OVRCameraRig. Pull it into your scene hierarchy.
21. Disable or remove your existing Main Camera.
22. Go to Edit > Project Settings > Player. Go to the "Android" tab.
23. Under "Other Settings", set Package Name to "com.{your_domain}.{your_app_name}", replacing the bracketed names with appropriate names
24. Change Minimum API Level to 21.
25. Under "XR Settings", under "Virtual Reality SDKs", tap + and add Oculus.
26. From your menu bar, select Oculus Platform > Edit Settings. A new inspector appears. For "Gear VR App id", fill in the "app id" from step 12. Make sure "Build Settings" has virtual reality support checked, and the bundle identifier is the same as in step 23.

## Build and run

27. Open the menu File > Build Settings. Choose Android.
28. Set Build System to "Internal".
29. Select your device under "Run Device". It should be called "Oculus Pacific" or something.
30. Press Build And Run. Hooray, now you're running your VR game on your Oculus Go!

[image: build and run configuration dialog]

Comment: this is helpful for setting build/graphic settings: https://developer.oculus.com/blog/tech-note-unity-settings-for-mobile-vr/

Comment: @palebone wow, that's really comprehensive! Thanks! :) (maybe they should have a template project with all of that set up though :S)

Comment: Agreed, there are some shortcuts that address some issues covered in the blog in the tools>Oculus>performance lint tool